# iOS photo library has totally changed

Tags: iphone, camera, photo, ios4

Until iPhone OS 4 I have read that /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/APPLE100 JPG files and extracted exif information such as location, thumbnails and other.

However, in the iOS4 the situation totally changed. The JPGs disappeared and I have no idea where to get locational information an open pictures.
Give me your light, please.

Comment: And this is why you shouldn't be accessing things outside your app's sandbox. Because things break when they change.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official framework for this now; look up AssetsLibrary in the docs. The way you go about it is very different, but the API is supported and will continue to work in future versions.